# Swift_TransportException on sending email

Tags: php, laravel, email, ubuntu, smtp

Cant send email on registration
(NOte: I m using Ubuntu)
here is my .env config

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=cxx2ca6xxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=44dd3xx402fae
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

i have also run these commands 
Php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear

```
Swift_TransportException {#1578 ▼
  #message: "Connection could not be established with host  [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0]"
  #code: 0
  #file: "/var/www/html/theBowlOne-FleetCart/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php"
  #line: 269
  trace: {▶}
}
```

Comment: This is most likely internet connection or DNS resolution problem

Comment: @Muhammad another user was curious in a now-deleted post: "_Did you change the pre-build emails content/notification messages on the FleetCart script? I used the same script but I want to change the emails if you can tell me how and where to change those in the php pages?_"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was solved there.the smtp settings was coming from database not from .env file.